# Block certain IPs using .htaccess behind Cloudflare

Tags: .htaccess, cloudflare

I use Cloudflare for my site so usual .htaccess rule won't work. I need to block certain IPs to access my website.

I found this one but won't work:

```
SetEnvIf X-FORWARDED-FOR 1.1.1.1 deny
order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from env=deny
```

I also tried this with the same result..

```
RewriteEngine On
SetEnvIf X-FORWARDED-FOR 109.100.238.188 deniedip
order allow,deny
deny from env=deniedip
```

Comment: It should be `deny from env=deny` since you are setting the deny environment variable on certain ips

Comment: i changed env=allow but nothing new..

Comment: I am not familiar with how Cloudflare does things. Afaik Cloudflare is a cdn, meaning that a lot of communication only goes as far as the cdn endpoint and will never reach your server. Is [this page](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168306-Is-there-a-tutorial-for-Page-Rules-) of any help?

Answer (score 0):

"I use Cloudflare for my site so usual .htaccess rule won't work."

These rules should still work fine as long as you have something set to [restore visitor IP bac](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/sections/200038166-How-do-I-restore-original-visitor-IP-to-my-server-logs-)k to your logs/server ([CloudFlare IPs](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips) will show without a mod, which could throw things off a little bit).

Comment: I thnk most people finding this page are looking for it because they cant install mod_cloudflare or do things to the same effect. Like me.